# Alternate method for 'new Date().getVarDate()' for other browser in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, getdate

I am new to JavaScript Date object, I am using the new Date().getVarDate() which will returns  ‘VT_DATE’.

```
   new Date().getVarDate()
   [date] Wed Jul 21 2021 04:18:43 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

This works in IE 11 but not in all other major browsers like Chrome, firefox, etc,,.    It would be helpful if I get any help to know the alternative JavaScript function that will return the same return value as getVarDate() in other major browsers.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need `VT_DATE` specifically?

Comment: It's deprecated method. I would recommend using toUTCString()

Comment: @Bharat is something deprecated if it was never included in most browsers? (not being rude btw)

Comment: To my knowledge it was originally created so that it can work with activeX controls and that was the reason it was supported only in IE For more info https://contest-server.cs.uchicago.edu/ref/JavaScript/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/Date.html

Comment: Can't you just use `new Date()` or `Date()`?

Comment: Also, I think the VT_DATE, VT is COM VARIANT

Comment: *getVarDate* is not a standard method of [*Date* instances](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-properties-of-the-date-prototype-object). An equivalent string is returned by [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring), so `new Date().toString()`.